# How to run Warcraft III on Ubuntu 13.04 i386?

Tags: 13.04, wine

I am trying to run Warcraft III (Doat 1) on Ubuntu 13.04, but every time I try to run it with 'wine' the computer's resolution changes and the computer carries on as normal.

I have done a 'top' command to see if there are any run-away or rouge processes, but none to close or terminate.

I have Warcraft III in a folder already installed to flash, ready to plug and play.

If there is another way to do this i would like some pointers.

Comment: 13.04 is end of life and no longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

I'd follow the most recent tips available at [appdb.winehq.org](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=3126).

Espacially:

> **What works**
>
> The game doesn't work but has a workaround
>
> **What does not**
>
> The game crash at start if winegstreamer is not disabled (in winecfg
>   in dll overrides section)
>
> Also, it's not possible to move the mouse to more than 1/3 of the
>   screen if emulated desktop is not set in winecfg (graphic tab).
>
> This last option is also useful if you use 2 screens because without
>   it, your 2 screens will show the same image with 2 different
>   resolutions (and it will screw your nvidia-settings configuration)